# Where can I make a modification or suggestion for Google Geocode API response, specifically the formatted_address field?

Tags: google-maps-api, geocoding

I was wondering where I can make a suggestion to modify a Google Maps geocode API response. Specifically the formatted_address field

Here is why : Usually airport type locations always have in their formatted_address field the airport code e.g: [(JFK)](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=A%C3%A9roport%20international%20John-F.-Kennedy). This is the case for almost every airport I tried to geocode.

But this one [Aéroport Marrakech-Ménara](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=A%C3%A9roport%20Marrakech-M%C3%A9nara,%20M%C3%A9nara,%20Marrakech,%20Maroc) is missing the airport code

Where do you think I can suggest this modification so that the formatted_address follows the standard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue trackers for various Google Maps API are here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/